# Git undo unpushed commit after merge revert

Tags: git

I didn't push my todays working to origin. Then try to merge another branch. Despite of much confilicts, i run `git reset --merge ORIG_HEAD`. That remove my local commits. How could these commits rollback.

I read some topics but couldn't find the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the result of `git reflog master`. It lists the previous states of your master branch. You should be able to find a valid state there.

Comment: great tip. `0e13da9 master@{6}: commit: Merge branch 'development'`. i need 4 commits before **0e13da9**. Is that possible?